# How to copy value from hardcoded variable to setPorperty one in JSTL/EL?

Tags: java, jsp, variables, jstl

What is the most beautiful way to copy the value from a hardcoded JSP variable into an EL variable?

This can be done with the following JSP

```
<% request.setAttribute("mode", mode); %>
```

but is it possible to do the same in EL? Maybe `useBean` is applicable somehow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a setProperty method for request. Do you mean setAttribute? I think this is want you want: `<c:set var="mode"><%= mode %></c:set>` Note: use "var" attribute not "name".

Comment: Thanks! How is it differ from <c:set name="mode" value="<%= mode %>" />?